# Working with days which don't start at midnight

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, datetime, time, schedule

I'm working on an application where I have a schedule where first item start at 5am and the last item ends at 3am of the next day, but I need to treat it as if it's the same day.

I know it will involve a lot of custom date queries on my models, but I'd like to know if there's a good approach I can do in Rails, to handle this "hour shift"

Somewhat related questions I found before posting:

- [Scheduling events, and having events cross midnight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853284/scheduling-events-and-having-events-cross-midnight)
- [Working with days which don't start at midnight in NodaTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053150/working-with-days-which-dont-start-at-midnight-in-nodatime)

Comment: Are your times in GMT or a local date time format?

Comment: I'm storing all dates in GMT, and applying timezone based on user preferences

Comment: Do you want to query to fetch all items scheduled between 5am to 3am?

Comment: If I need items from "day 4", I need to get items from "day 4 starting at 5am until day 5 at 4:59am"

Answer (score 0):

You can use following date range while querying.

```
Between DateTime.now.midnight + 3.days + 5.hours and DateTime.now.midnight + 4.days + 5.hours
```

Here, you can use (n-1).days to n.days

Hope this is useful